# Map NSEvent keyCode to virtual key code

Tags: macos, nsevent

[NSEvent keyCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/keyCode) gives a keyboard scan code, which is a hardware specific code representing the physical key. I want to convert the scan code to a virtual key code, which is the logical key based on the users keyboard layout (QWERTY, AZERTY, etc).

In Windows I can do this via [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). What is the OS X equivalent?

Comment: For someone coming here with a similar problem. Have a look at [KeyNaming](https://github.com/JensAyton/KeyNaming) library.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The virtual key code is precisely *not* based on the user's keyboard layout. It indicates which key was pressed, not what character that key would produce nor how it's labeled.

For example, `kVK_ANSI_A` (from Carbon/HIToolbox/Events.h, value `0x00`) does *not* mean the key which produces the 'A' character, it means the key which is in the position that the 'A' key is in an ANSI standard keyboard. If a French keyboard layout is active, that key will produce 'Q'. If the physical keyboard is a French keyboard, that key will probably be labeled 'Q', too.

So, the virtual key code is sort of akin to a scan code, but from an idealized, standard keyboard. It is, as noted, hardware-independent. It is also independent of the keyboard layout.

To translate from the virtual key code to a character, you can use [`UCKeyTranslate()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Unicode_Utilities_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000122-CH1g-F10792). You need the 'uchr' data for the current keyboard layout. You can get that using [`TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006199-CH3-SW3) and then [`TISGetInputSourceProperty()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Reference/TextInputSourcesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006199-CH3-SW1) with `kTISPropertyUnicodeKeyLayoutData` as the property key.

You also need the keyboard type code. I believe it's still supported to use `LMGetKbdType()` to get that, even though it's no longer documented except in the legacy section. If you don't like that, you can obtain a `CGEvent` from the `NSEvent`, <strike>create a `CGEventSource` from that using [`CGEventCreateSourceFromEvent()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-SW1), and then use [`CGEventSourceGetKeyboardType()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-DontLinkElementID_14)</strike>and call `CGEventGetIntegerValueField()` with `kCGKeyboardEventKeyboardType` to get the keyboard type.

Of course, it's much easier to simply use [`-[NSEvent characters]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/characters) or [`-[NSEvent charactersIgnoringModifiers]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/charactersIgnoringModifiers). Or, if you're implementing a text view, send key-down events to [`-[NSResponder interpretKeyEvents:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/interpretKeyEvents:) (as discussed in [Cocoa Event Handling Guide: Handling Key Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW1)) or [`-[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextInputContext_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextInputContext/handleEvent:) (as discussed in [Cocoa Text Architecture Guide:Text Editing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW1)). Either of those will call back to the view with the appropriate action selector, like `moveBackward:`, or with `-insertText:` if the keystroke (in context of recent events and the input source) would produce text.

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining virtual key codes from the Mac perspective, it seems to differ from Windows. It seems easiest to test charactersIgnoringModifiers for characters my app cares about.

Comment: What are the API calls as of now, since Carbon Core and Carbon in general got deprecated?

Comment: @Julien, not all of Carbon is deprecated. The functions I mention here are not.

Comment: Hm, interesting. The function itself is not marked as deprecated, but the whole module instead, without mentioning it in the function documentation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the NSEvent documentation, `-[NSEvent keyCode]` returns the hardware-independent virtual key code.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, for some reason I read that as hardware-dependent, I guess because that seems to be the behavior in my app. I guess I have more investigating to do. Nothing to see here, carry on...